# Optimizing SQS Lambda configuration for single concurrency microservice composition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, message-queue, amazon-sqs

Apologies for the title. It's hard to summarise what I'm trying to accomplish.

Basically let me define a service to be an SQS Queue + A Lambda function.

A service (represented by square brackets below) performs a given task, where the queue is the input interface, processes the input, and outputs on to the queue of the subsequent service.

```
      Service 1              Service 2             Service 3

[(APIG) -> (Lambda)] -> [(SQS) -> (Lambda)] -> [(SQS) -> (Lambda)] -> ...
```

**Service 1:** Consumes the request and payload, splits it into messages and passes on to the queue of the next service.

**Service 2:** This service does not have a reserved concurrency. It validates each message on the queue, and if valid, passes on to the next service.

**Service 3**: Processes each message in the queue (ideally in batches of approximately 100). The lambda here **must** have a reserved concurrency of 1 (as it hits an API that can't process multiple requests concurrently).

Currently I have the following configuration on Service 3.

- Default visibility timeout of queue = 5 minutes
- Lambda timeout = 5 minutes
- Lambda reserved concurrency = 1

**Problem 1**: Service 3 consumes `x` items off the queue and if it finishes processing them within 30 seconds I expect the queue to process the next `x` items off the queue immediately (ideally `x=100`). Instead, it seems to always wait 5 minutes before taking the next batch of messages off the queue, even if the lambda completes in 30 seconds.

**Problem 2**: Service 3 typically consumes a few messages at a time (inconsistent) rather than batches of 100.

A couple of more notes:

- In service 3 I do not explicitly delete messages off the queue using the lambda. AWS seems to do this itself when the lambda successfully finishes processing the messages
- In service 2 I have one item per message. And so when I send messages to Service 3 I can only send 10 items at a time, which is kind of annoying. Because `queue.send_messages(Entries=x)`, `len(x)` cannot exceed 10.

Does anyone know how I solve Problem 1 and 2? Is it an issue with my configuration? If you require any further information please ask in comments.

Thanks

Comment: haven't had the time to go through your question entirely just yet, but the max amount of batches you can consume is 10

Comment: one other thing is that it is known that lambda functions draining SQS queues with a reserved concurrency of 1 is problematic. I am looking where it is but it's somewhere in the internet. As soon as I find it I'll drop the link here.

Comment: The lambda should only consume one single batch of 100 messages at at time. Also that's interesting I would like to see why this is and potential solutions

Comment: https://medium.com/@zaccharles/lambda-concurrency-limits-and-sqs-triggers-dont-mix-well-sometimes-eb23d90122e0 here it is, @Greg.

Comment: but that's what i'm saying: it cannot consume a batch of 100. the max size of the batch it can consume is 10 at a time

Comment: Does this mean I should be supplying say 10 items in a single message payload? Thats ok I guess

Comment: Thanks for the link. Reading now

Comment: yes! 10 (messages) x10 (items per message) will fix your issue (this is the only decent solutions anyways). you're more than welcome, hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Thanks :)

Comment: Any idea why the lambda waits 5 minutes until it processes the next batch, rather than immediately after it finishes the previous batch?

Comment: Also any idea why it consumes like 2-3 messages at a time, rather than 10 (which it is now set to)

Comment: No idea about the 5 minutes thing. Regarding the batch thing, it’s not guaranteed that Lambda functions will always pick up batches of 10. Unfortunately there’s no work around it

Answer (score 1):

Both your problems and notes indicate misconfigured SQS and/or Lambda function.

> In service 3 I do not explicitly delete messages off the queue using
>   the lambda. AWS seems to do this itself when the lambda successfully
>   finishes processing the messages.

This is definitely not the case here as it would go agains the reliability of SQS. How would SQS know that the message was successfully processed by your Lambda function? SQS doesn't care about consumers and doesn't really communicate with them and that is exactly the reason why there is a thing such as visibility timeout. SQS deletes message in two cases, either it receives `DeleteMessage` API call specifying which message to be deleted via `ReceiptHandle` or you have set up redrive policy with maximum receive count set to 1. In such case, SQS will automatically send message to dead letter queue when if it receives it more than 1 time which means that every message that was **returned** to the queue will be send there instead of staying in the queue. Last thing that can cause this is a low value of `Message Retention Period` (min 60 seconds) which will drop the message after `x` seconds.

> Problem 1: Service 3 consumes x items off the queue and if it finishes
>   processing them within 30 seconds I expect the queue to process the
>   next x items off the queue immediately (ideally x=100). Instead, it
>   seems to always wait 5 minutes before taking the next batch of
>   messages off the queue, even if the lambda completes in 30 seconds.

This simply doesn't happen if everything is working as it should. If the lambda function finishes in 30 seconds, if there is reserved concurrency for the function and if there are messages in the queue then it will start processing the message right away.

The only thing that could cause is that your lambda (together with concurrency limit) is timing out which would explain those 5 minutes. Make sure that it really finishes in 30 seconds, you can monitor this via CloudWatch. The fact that the message has been successfully processed doesn't necessarily mean that the function has returned. Also make sure that there are messages to be processed when the function ends.

> Problem 2: Service 3 typically consumes a few messages at a time
>   (inconsistent) rather than batches of 100.

It can never consume 100 messages since the limit is 10 (messages in the sense of SQS message not the actual data that is stored within the message which can be anywhere up to 256 KB, possibly "more" using extended SQS library or similar custom solution). Moreover, there is no guarantee that the Lambda will receive 10 messages in each batch. It depends on the `Receive Message Wait Time` setting. If you are using short polling (1 second) then only subset of servers which are storing the messages will be polled and a single message is stored only on a subset of those servers. If those two subsets do not match when the message is polled, the message is not received in that batch. You can control this by increasing polling interval, `Receive Message Wait Time`, (max 20 seconds) but even if there are not enough messages in the queue when the timer finishes, the batch will still be received with fewer messages, possibly zero.

And as it was mentioned in the comments, using this strategy with concurrency set to low number can lead to some problems. Another thing is that you need to ensure that rate at which messages are produced is somehow consistent with the time it takes for one instance of lambda function to process the message otherwise you will end up with constantly growing queue, possibly losing messages after they outlive the `Message Retention Period`.